# Extjs 3.4 how to change the tooltip of grid column header on Run time?

Tags: extjs

```
tooltip: dizionario.traduci("${GRCLI_SW_T_PERIODO}"),
```

This is my Sample Code, I am using `Extjs 3.4.0` am trying to update the tooltip of grid column on runtime, I am using `column.tooltip = "abc"` it changes the tooltip config but on mouse hover I am not able to see updated tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is normal and easy. Actually, if you change the tooltip from tooltip config of extjs you need to refresh your DOM
You just need to get grid first and then you get the column on which you want to change the tooltip.

Code:

```
gridColumn.tooltip = "updatedTooltip";
```

Then for refresh DOM you just do:

```
gridPanel.getView().updateHeaders();
```

Thank You :)